# ZipFile module creating .pyc file

Tags: python, zip, archive

I can't find any info on this but when I try and create a zip archive in Python it creates a .pyc instead.

```
#!/Python27/python

import zipfile

z = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')
z.write('README.txt')
z.close()
```

This is the result of running the script.

[image]

Comment: Your code would not even run

Comment: It is `ZipFile` not `Zipfile`

Comment: Still not working, and it did run, produced the same results, just a .pyc file

Comment: did you call your file zipfile? You should be getting errors so it should be obvious something is not working

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: is your script called zipfile.py?

Comment: :/ I feel stupid :) DONT CALL YOUR SCRIPT ZIPFILE.py

Comment: lol you are not alone, happens every day.

Comment: @damorton I only know this because I lost an hour solving it a few weeks ago.

Comment: It was driving me mad I couldn't understand why there was no info about this anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you're running (or some other script you have) is actually called `zipfile.py`, and so Python is actually first looking in the folder your script is in to find a module called `zipfile`. When it finds this script, it imports that instead of the actual module.

Any time a script is imported to another Python file, Python automatically creates a compiled `.pyc` file resulting in that `zipfile.pyc`. If you rename your file to something more specific (and also fix your typo) you should be able to avoid this problem.